# What does req.body.rid in a post request mean?

Tags: node.js

I have this block of code that is not being called for some reason. I would like to know what req.body.rid in the second line is referring to, and if possible, why this block of code is being overlooked.

```
app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
    var curr_rid = req.body.rid;
    json.user_data[0]["final_id"] = curr_rid;
    let data_final = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
        var filepath = "data/user_" + amznWorkId + ".json";
        fs.writeFileSync(filepath, data_final, (err) => {
            if(err) throw err;
    });
    console.log(json);
});
```

Comment: Some kind of id, sent via the request body?

Comment: `rid` comes from the client you make the request. I assume that the content-type of the request is `application/json` and rid is part of the JSON payload.